# Single webform on multi-language site with different url aliases

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I have multi-language site with webform. I want to use the same (single) webform for each language so I used *Webform Localization* module to translate the webform via string translation. Everything works, but the urls now looks like `/en/node/123` and `/cs/node/123`.

I'd like to have separate url aliases for each language, e.g. `/en/my-form` and `/cs/muj-formular`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using administration interface.

Firs, Go to admin/config/search/path and click "Add alias".

On "Add alias" page:

1. Select language.
2. Fill the field "Existing system path" with your webform node/{nid_number}
3. Fill the field "Path alias" with desired alias for that language.